# Favorite tags on Stack Exchange not updating

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, tag-watching

I add some tags on Stack Overflow, but it shows "No favorite tags found" on my homepage at Stack Exchange.
Here are the screenshots.

[image: screenshot of my favorite tags on stackoverflow]

[image: screenshot of my favorite tags on stackexchange]

Comment: post your image...(I forgot it was +5 for up votes...it'll sink in one day!)

Comment: although likely you could describe the problem without an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Stack Exchange favorite tags filter]

If you haven't you could try the "Re-Sync Favorite Tags filter" link...

**Edit**
Do you have the show details link? -- if you do not, maybe the bug is that until you have a single tag (or until it thinks you have a single tag) you cannot "expand" to re-sync.
[image: Show Details link]

**Edit 2**
My guess is that until it thinks you have at least 1 tag, you've not got access to the refresh link. This to me sounds like a bug. Although I presume the situation will resolve after a period of time when a sync is scheduled.

**Edit 3** - Potential work around
You might be able to work around the problem by just doing what the link *would* have done if clicked (obviously not ideal).

1. On the page where you can see your favourites (or not see them either way) look at your URL. It should be something like: `http://stackexchange.com/filters/<NUMBER>/favorite-tags`
2. Change the URL to be the following (obviously substituting `<NUMBER>` for your number from step 1. URL: `http://stackexchange.com/filters/re-sync/<NUMBER>`
3. Hit enter (or whatever) in your browser to potentially cause the refresh

This would be the equivalent of clicking the link *if* it were visible/accessible. <strike>This may not work but presumably will.</strike>  Confirmed by OP that this worked.

Comment: But I can't find the "Re-Sync Favorite Tags filter" link on the page :(

Comment: @blankyao, I'm not really sure at this stage because the link is there for me...you can post an image now anyway if that helps.

Comment: @blankyao, see edit...

Comment: It doesn't have the "show details" link :(

Comment: @blankyao, added a potential work around for you...