# Where did "My Filters" link go for the new Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to “Tagged Questions” on the Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123907/what-happened-to-tagged-questions-on-the-stack-exchange-site)

On the new Stack Exchange page, I can't seem to find the "My Filter" link where I had saved a master filter for tags on every site.

Similar to the [image shown in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103645/favorite-tags-on-stack-exchange-not-updating).

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAC63.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click "Hot Questions" link, you'll get to the page having two tabs: *Hottest from All Sites* and *My Filters*. On that page, select *My filters* tab to get to the master filter.

Note if you want to edit the filter, you will need to click *show details* to get to the *edit* link.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/coAIe.jpg]

Comment: Why did they hide it under that? I mean are my filters really considered "hot questions"? ...probably not

Comment: @ShawnMelton good question. Maybe the reasoning was like _my-filtered questions are hot for me_

Answer (score 0):

When you login into Stack Exchange it will come along with "Hottest from All Sites" link